# Define distance between BORDER points when creating clusters

Tags: clustering, cluster-tolerance

I need to create clusters based on the certain distance not between core point, but between border points. In other words I need clusters where distance between border point of one cluster to the border point of any other cluster not less than e.g. 5 km. Preferably ArcGIS Pro but would be happy to hear any ideas.

Comment: Triangulate points. Extract TIN edges and delete long ones. Remaining connected components of you graph are clusters that you need. Pro comes with networkx package.

Comment: On 2nd thought, just buffer remaining edges, dissolve to multipart and explode to single parts. !Shape!.convexHull() if necessary...

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it.